# Get Headers/Cookies from Bottle API request

Tags: python, request, bottle

I was making an API call to a **Bottle** service and was passing `headers` in the call using Python's **request** Library.

```
requests.get('http://localhost/API/call', headers={"cat":"tax"})
```

I wanted to get the custom headers passed in the function that gets called through the API call.

Using `bottle.request.headers` I get the following data:
[image]

Now, the custom header I passed is present in the `environ` dictionary with key/value `'HTTP_CAT':tax`.

Same thing for `cookies`. Cookie data can be retrieved using `bottle.request.cookies`

How can I filter out only the custom header that I am passing in the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "filter," but the typical way to retrieve request headers from Bottle is with `get_header`:

```
cat_value = request.get_header('cat')
```

Bottle also has a specific API for retrieving individual cookies. Perhaps there's a good reason you're going down to the raw environ, but if not, then you should be using these built-in methods.

PS, you may also want to prefix your custom headers with "X-", e.g. `X-Cat`.

Comment: `request.get_header()` would work only if I know the header keys being passed. I wanted it to work for any header values passed. Prefixing custom headers seems a good option.

Comment: Prefix custom headers with "X-" was required but no more. Old habits behing long to disapear... better prefix with something relevant to your app "MyApp-<header_name>"

Answer (score 0):

To get all headers from the request, just cast the headers property to a dict. Tested to be working on bottle==0.12.25

```
headers = dict(request.headers)
```